# Finding the path between two vertices in Neo4j using Gremlin

Tags: neo4j, gremlin

I'm trying to find in a Neo4j database a path in between two vertices, assuming I have code that look like this

```
newschool = g.addVerttex();
newschool.Title = 'A nice school';

newuser = g.addVertex();
newuser.name = 'student';

g.addEdge(newuser, g.V.filter{it.Title == 'school'}.next(), 'goesto');
```

I can get back the edge that I wanted if I know the id of both vertices, but of course this is not dynamic:

```
g.v(2).outE.inV.retain([g.v(1)]).back(2);
==> e[1][2-goesto->1]
```

so then I tried to change this to be more dynamic expanding on the working query:

```
g.V.filter{it.name == 'student'}.outE.inV.retain([g.V.filter{it.Title == 'A nice school'}]).back(2);

g.v(g.V.filter{it.name == 'student'}.id).outE.inV.retain([g.v(g.V.filter{it.Title == 'A nice school'}.id)]).back(2)
```

none of that worked of course...

Why is `g.V.filter{it.name =='student'}` and `g.v(2)` different? why is `g.V.filter{it.name == 'student'}.id` not the same as `2`?

What did I miss? How do I get this to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think you are iterating your pipeline inside the retain.  Note my Gremlin session below using the toy TinkerGraph:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]                                     
gremlin> g.v(1).out.retain([g.v(4)])
==>v[4]
gremlin> g.v(1).out.retain([g.V.filter{it.name=='josh'}])
gremlin> g.v(1).out.retain([g.V.filter{it.name=='josh'}.next()])
==>v[4]
```

Make sure you `next()` inside the retain:

```
g.V.filter{it.name == 'student'}.outE.inV.retain([g.V.filter{it.Title == 'A nice school'}.next()]).back(2)
```

Comment: Cool! this is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks! I'm very new to the gremlin language, I read through the document about `next()` http://gremlindocs.com/#methods/pipe-next but I was not able to fully make sense of it, both `g.V.filter{it.Title == 'A nice school'}` and `g.V.filter{it.Title == 'A nice school'}.next()` gives me the same thing when I executed them on the console, how come I was able to retain the version from `next()` and not the one from `filter()`?

Comment: Remember that the console iterates the pipeline for you.  When you press enter, it basically calls `next()` until the pipeline is exhausted.  If you wrap your pipeline inside of a closure, the console doesn't know to help you inside there. The same thing applies if you try to execute your gremlin line inside of a groovy script...there is nothing to iterate the pipeline, so you must either `next()` it out yourself or `iterate()` to generate side-effects.

Comment: so essentially `next()` executes the pipeline for you, and when I create a new pipeline inside `retain()`, it is not auto executed, and therefore I need to execute it myself by calling `next()`. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: `next()` just pops the next item out of the pipeline.  i would go so far as to say that it "executes the pipeline", but you basically have the idea.  something (whether it's you or the gremlin console) needs to  pop items out of the pipeline (or `iterate()` for side-effects) or it will just sit there and do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

```
g.v(1).out.loop(1){it.object != g.v(2)}.path
```

In English:

"Start from vertex 1 and loop over outgoing edges while the object you reach is not vertex 2. Return the path."

See http://gremlindocs.com for more information on such patterns.

Comment: Hi Marko, thanks for the answer, but as I've mentioned that if I were to know the index of the vertex, I am able to find the edge that I want by `g.v(2).outE.inV.retain([g.v(1)]).back(2);` my question is on the two query below that I've expanded from the working query, why those doesn't work as I've expected them to work.